# Is materialism actually material?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, physicalism, materialism

[physicalism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/physicalism/) allows for forces such as gravity which on the face of it are not material as say the cup of tea I have to hand. So materialism literally taken seems to be wrong.

But looking at this more closely (and taking physicalism to be correct) the cup is not material either - the reason why the cup doesn't fall through the table is due to electromagnetic forces.

Hence materialism seems to vanish altogether!

(The SEP however does allow a more expansive definition of materialism which is more or less synonymous with physicalism)

Comment: "The SEP however does allow a more expansive definition of materialism which is more or less synonymous with physicalism"; this is the sense in which I have always taken it.

Comment: @dennis: so do I, at least since I understood physics. But I still find it strange when I reflect on it.

Comment: Just a few thoughts in passing :) There's a phenomenological problem about invisibility I feel like you're trying to point to -- it might be constructive to try to consider Merleau-Ponty and Husserl in this context (or maybe even Serres -- *The Birth of Physics* seems possibly relevant.)

Comment: @weissman: I think there is a phenomenal difference between materialism & physicalism. Objects at hand have a materiality that gravity for example doesn't. I'm not sure that this is phenomenological in Husserls sense. But then I don't know anything about Husserl.

Comment: "Materialism" predates the term "physicalism" and carries with it a lot of the older (now seen as inaccurate) notions of physics/physicality. The term *physicalism*, it seems, was an attempt to distance the emerging views of materialism from the old ones, and using a new name helped facilitate that. That said, the term materialism covers a range of distinct theories, going as far as being synonymous with the more modern "physicalist" theories. But yes, I'm sure the older materialism theories did not address the point you make, as the creators of such theories did not know about such concepts.

Answer (score 5):

Especially given what you observe about electromagnetic forces, not to mention atomic theory post 1911 (c.f. the Rutherford model) and gravity post 1916 (c.f. general relativity theory), the notion of what is "material" becomes a rather significant question. To say nothing of special relativity and the Einstein equation linking matter to energy...

I would, as a matter of practical discussion, include antimatter and energy, and in fact anything which is understood to obey mechanical laws, into the notion of what "materialism" accepts as pertinent 'substances'. It seems to me that materialism was originally presented in opposition to dualism and idealism; and inasmuch as there is any distinction between the monism of materialism and that of idealism, it is that the notion of matter following mechanical laws of motion being primary versus consciousness and/or spirit being primary as the fundamental nature of reality. Aside from taking different positions on the hard problem of consciousness, the pertinent difference is whether mechanism or intention is the most important principle of dynamics: and materialism is clearly on the side of mechanism.

Physicalism is therefore the natural modern formulation of materialism, and perhaps is best construed as an elaboration of it in which it is recognised that 'matter' was a potentially narrow description of what one ought to consider pertinent. (Though it is still perhaps feasible, if unfashionable, to try to interpret energy as merely describing kinetic behaviour and potential.)

Answer (score 2):

If the question was not only about whether materialism and physicalism are the same I want to add a comment about what you said about gravity and electromagnetic forces.

Natural forces can seem non physical at first glance and I hear many people talk about them as being the invisible laws that govern the universe. But a less magical way to view it is to see that all natural laws or forces are just functions of matter. If you take away the matter the force disappear as well. Gravity and electromagnetic forces does not exist by themselves as non-physical entities, they are just a way to talk about material change as apposed to mater frozen in time (like your cup of tea).

Comment: Technically, the solutions to general relativity in which black holes are usually formulated actually have no matter at all. The hole itself is not material; it's merely the shape of spacetime at a certain location. We simply suppose that the equations can have similar solutions when matter is actually present nearby to the hole.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you are saying, but the way I understand it a black hole contains a lot of matter and is only a metaphorical 'hole'. If you try to describe spacetime you must necessarily talk about matter. "The curvature of spacetime is directly related to the energy and momentum of whatever matter and radiation are present." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) Or are you saying that "the hole" is only a "description of gravity as a geometric property" and not a real object i.e. it is just a model? (but is it not still a model which try to describe how matter is moving?)

Comment: I mean that while black holes can arise due to the collapse of matter, one can have [a pure black hole spacetime with no matter whatsoever](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-singularities/#GeoNatBlaHol). Since a black hole is a feature *of spacetime* which constrains the worldlines of matter --- specifically, it either remains forever outside or crosses the event horizon exactly once --- one should think of gravitational collapse as being merely a sufficient condition for the presence of a purely geometrical feature in spacetime.

Comment: Is this just an argument about how to define matter? i.e. is the argument saying that 'because matter in a black hole has no density it is not really a 'thing' anymore but instead spacetime'? or is it saying that black holes can form without matter?

Comment: What does it mean for the matter to be in the black hole? It is not that it has no density; it is that what defines the black hole is its geometry and not the matter inside of it, and as the SEP link I gave you points out, you can have a black hole without matter. A black hole may be *caused* by matter collapsing, but the hole *consists* of a particular geometry of space-time.

Comment: To me it means that: The matter is described with the help of a mental model we call a 'black hole'. I saw in your profile that you seem to have more knowledge about this topic than me :) but I don't understand HOW the matter disappear? ha ha How can 'you have a black hole without matter?

I understand that geometry of space-time is just a mental model (about matter, but still just a model), so is 'the hole' which 'consists of a particular geometry' not just a part of this mental model? or are you saying that it is a non-material existing entity outside of our heads?

Comment: The matter doesn't necessarily disappear. There are various ways to approach it, including that the singularity only exists at "the end of time", so that the matter inside exists until the end of time; it merely reaches the end of time in finite subjective time. The point is this: you can have a black hole with matter inside of it, or with **no** matter inside of it. Therefore our physical *theories* admit the possibility of gravity without matter. Obviously we care mostly about universes with matter in them, but it means that in our best theories, we must worry about more than just matter.

Comment: You say that you can have a black hole with no matter inside of it but I see no reasons for believing it since all the evidence you have provided is about mental models. That our physical theories can be stretched to admit the possibility of gravity without matter does not mean that there is no matter; I think you have to stretch your definitions of matter in order to allow it. Please help me answer the question of time I just posted. Is the "end of time" you are talking about when matter is so compressed that it does not move at all any more i.e. it exist in the form of light?

Comment: I am of course talking about mental models; but if you don't believe in those, it is not clear why you should take seriously the notion that I exist, since (presumably) for you I am only a hypothesis on which to base some of the text you see appearing on this website and other bits of the internet. Or, more seriously, why you should bother with the idea of "gravity" or "physics".

Comment: I take mental models very seriously if they directly or indirectly help us understand something material i.e. something in reality. I thought you where saying that the black hole model was not actually describing matter at all; neither the features nor the functions of matter. But maybe I understood you wrong. This is not an easy topic :)

Comment: Part of the problem is that it is difficult to determine what knowledge or ideas you may have that is not merely a mental model. Suffice it to say that it is generally accepted that black holes exist, and consist of a deformation of spacetime; while they may contain matter (in the sense that a box can contain objects), it does not consist of matter, any more than electromagnetic waves are transmitted through a medium. If that is the case, it is difficult to avoid the useful convention of saying that spacetime is a 'thing' in its own right, which is not made of matter but interacts with it.

Comment: Were you trying to say from the beginning that the hole part of black holes (or the spacetime concept) is 'technically' speaking not really about matter because it is not describing a feature or a function of matter? That it is rather describing a mental model (or an object drawn on a piece of paper or on a computer); it is an abstraction which only potentially indirectly refer to something physical, in the sense that it might be able to help us predict certain phenomenons; that it is not describing a function of matter in terms of cause and effect?

Comment: Given that we only ever understand the world by our mental models, and that anything we say is just our attempt to come to grips with the raw stimuli which we are presented with --- I mean that our best model of the world includes a thing which we give the name "spacetime", which we do not describe as an instance of "matter"; and we explain "gravity" as an interaction between matter and spacetime. You can try to describe everything that happens with spacetime as merely "relationships between matter", but this is as useful as describing all logical connectives in terms of "NAND" (ie. not very).

Comment: Bah, but there is no matter to be put away. Just energy. Sorry.

Answer (score -3):

Yep Agree. Materialism is a ideology. Ideology of declining all invisible (especially including God, spirit etc..). It is a simple ideology of people of 18-19th centuries, which did not know, that "materia" is, in original nature, an energy. Nuclear physics can say, hitting the table: "This table is empty space (almost), it is just an energy". Comparing distances between atom cores in a table and atom cores size could lead to such conclusion and therefore atom cores can be neglect from the material point of view. Not the same with it's energy.

Therefore all kind of simple materialism are wrong as their original postulates was wrong. But ideology of materialism is a bit wider. And ideology can be overrun just by another and (!) better ideology. Especially new clones of materialism, as dialectic m. and various socialism and communism ideologies need brand new and better explanation of specific questions raised by materialists.

Ideology respecting both, invisible internal character (as energy) and visible external form (as materia), both in balance, should appear. Also duality of all things (the plus-minus pattern) should be included. Such ideology should be acceptable by sciences and religions, otherwise new scepticism and new kind of materialism will appear.

Let's make a search for best option... My best tip is the Unification Thought, as Japanese and Latin America's communists in 1960's give strong direction **not to talk** with CAUSA members, giving UT lectures that time in countries where ideology of communism began to spread, which helped to collapse of communist structures in that countries. So I see that as a hammer to materialism.

Comment: If you wonder about the downvotes: While the question addresses how the label materialism could/should be understood in the context of the development of natural science from an epistemological point of view, your answer seems to address (polemically) dialectical/historical materialism, which is a sociological theory as well as a social doctrine. This misses the issue of the original question.

Comment: --- thats funny